# Accessing email from MySQL db to be use for sending email

Tags: php, email, foreach, laravel-5.1

I have a problem with my message notification using email.Why is that it generates an error inside the foreach.
The error is this part "$all_ngo" Undefined variable: all_ngo.

```
$pend = AddRequest::where('ship_id','=',$ship_id)->get();   
$all_ngo = [];
foreach ($pend as $id) {
    array_push($all_ngo, $id->ngo_id);
}

$orga_email  =  Auth::User()->orgainfo->orga_email;
$staffName  =   Auth::User()->orgainfo->inchargelname.' '. Auth::User()->orgainfo->inchargefname;  
$name = $scholars->scholar_fname.' '.$scholars->scholar_mname.' '.$scholars->scholar_lname;
$input =  array(
    'name' => $staffName,
    'email' => $orga_email,  
    'msgs' => 'asd' .' '. $name.'. '.'Hoping for your favorable response. Thank you!'
);
Mail::send('emails.mailMessage', $input,  function($message){
    $message->from('Somename@gmail.com');
    foreach ($all_ngo as $id3) {<-------Undefined variable: all_ngo
        $user = User::find($id3);
        $ngo_email2 = $user->ngo_email;
        $message->to($ngo_email2)->subject('Request For Sponsorship');
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `$all_ngo` is out of scope. You can solve this by adding a `global $all_ngo;` into the function:

```
Mail::send('emails.mailMessage', $input,  function($message) {
  global $all_ngo;

  $message->from('Somename@gmail.com');
  foreach ($all_ngo as $id3) {<-------Undefined variable: all_ngo
    $user = User::find($id3);
    $ngo_email2 = $user->ngo_email;
    $message->to($ngo_email2)->subject('Request For Sponsorship');
  }   
});
```

or allow the anonymous function to access the variable:

```
Mail::send('emails.mailMessage', $input,  function($message) use ($all_ngo) {
  $message->from('Somename@gmail.com');
  foreach ($all_ngo as $id3) {<-------Undefined variable: all_ngo
    $user = User::find($id3);
    $ngo_email2 = $user->ngo_email;
    $message->to($ngo_email2)->subject('Request For Sponsorship');
  }   
});
```

Comment: Sir thank you it's working now i use the 2nd option.